# "saved_model_cli show" on a keras+transformers model display different inputs and shapes that the one used for training

Tags: keras, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

I am using `transformers` `TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained` with 'bert-base-multilingual-uncased') and `keras` to build my model.

```
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

# metric
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

# optimizer
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, epsilon=epsilon)

# create and compile the Keras model in the context of strategy.scope
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(pretrained_weights,
                                                        num_labels=num_labels,
                                                        cache_dir=pretrained_model_dir)
model._name = 'tf_bert_classification'

# compile Keras model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=loss,
              metrics=[metric])
```

I am using `SST2` data, that are tokenize and the feed to the model for training. The data have the following shape:

```
    shape: (32,)
    dict structure
       dim: 3
       [input_ids       / attention_mask  / token_type_ids ]
       [(32, 128)       / (32, 128)       / (32, 128)      ]
       [ndarray         / ndarray         / ndarray        ]
```

and here an example:

```
({'input_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(32, 128), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[  101, 21270, 94696, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [  101,   143, 45100, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [  101, 24220,   102, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       ...,
       [  101, 11008, 10346, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [  101, 43062, 15648, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [  101, 13178, 18418, ...,     0,     0,     0]], dtype=int32)>, 'attention_mask': ....
```

As we can see we have `input_ids`  with shape (32, 128) where 32 is the batch size and 128 is the maxiumum length of the string (max for BERT is 512). We also have `attention_mask` and `token_type_ids` with the same structure.

I am able to train a model and to do prediction using `model.evaluate(test_dataset)`. All good.

The issue that I am having is that when I serve the model on GCP, then it require data in a different input shape and structure! I saw the same if I run the cli on the saved model:

```
saved_model_cli show --dir $MODEL_LOCAL --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default

The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['input_ids'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: (-1, 5)
      name: serving_default_input_ids:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['output_1'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 2)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

As we can see we only need to give `input_ids` and not (`attention_mask` and `token_type_ids`) and the sape is different. While the batch size is not defined (-1) which expected, the maxium length is 5 instead of 128!It was working 2 months ago and I probably introduce something that created this issue.

I tried few version of `Tensorfow` (`2.2.0` and `2.3.0`) and transformers (`2.8.0`, `2.9.0` and `3.0.2`). I cannot see the Keras'model input and outpu shape (None):

```
model.inputs


model.outputs


model.summary()

Model: "tf_bert_classification"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bert (TFBertMainLayer)       multiple                  167356416 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_37 (Dropout)         multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
=================================================================
Total params: 167,357,954
Trainable params: 167,357,954
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Any idea what could explain that the saved model require a different input that the one use for training! I could use the Keras functional API and defined the input shape but I am pretty sure the this code was working before.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such behavior when model was instantiated from pretrained one, then weights were loaded, and only then it was saved in fully-pledged keras format.
When I was loading the latter afterwards, it was not able to issue correct prediction because its signatures became garbage: attention_mask disappeared, seq_length changed, dummy None inputs appeared out of nowhere. So probably try to save your model in keras format right after fitting (without intermediary loading from weights), if that's your case.